# Keras : How to create a custom layer with weights when the input shape is unknow during compilation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer

I want to define a Pre-processing layer just after my input layer, ie it will use the mean and variance of a scaler that was computed before and apply it on my inputs before passing them to the Dense network.

Lambda layers do not work in my case because I want to save the model, the objective is that when applied on data, there is not need to process the inputs since it will be done in the early stage of the network.

Using K.variables for the mean and var works, but I would like to use weights instead and set trainable=False. This way they will be saved in the weights of the network and I don't have to provide them each time.

```py
class PreprocessLayer(Layer):                                                                                                                                                                               
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    Defines a layer that applies the preprocessing from a scaler                                                                                                                                            
    Needed because lambda layers are too fragile to be saved in a model                                                                                                                                     
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    def __init__(self, batch_size, mean, var, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                    
        self.b = batch_size                                                                                                                                                                                 
        self.m = mean                                                                                                                                                                                       
        self.v = var                                                                                                                                                                                        
        super(PreprocessLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)                                                                                                                                                     

    def build(self, input_shape):                                                                                                                                                                           
        self.mean = self.add_weight(name='mean',                                                                                                                                                            
                                  shape=(self.b,input_shape[1]),                                                                                                                                            
                                  initializer=tf.constant_initializer(self.m),                                                                                                                              
                                  trainable=False)                                                                                                                                                          
        self.var = self.add_weight(name='var',                                                                                                                                                              
                                  shape=(self.b,input_shape[1]),                                                                                                                                            
                                  initializer=tf.constant_initializer(self.v),                                                                                                                              
                                  trainable=False)                                                                                                                                                          
        super(PreprocessLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end                                                                                                                  

    def call(self, x):                                                                                                                                                                                      
        return (x-self.mean)/self.var                                                                                                                                                                       

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):                                                                                                                                                            
        return (input_shape[0],input_shape[1])                                                                                                                                                              
    def get_config(self):                                                                                                                                                                                   
        config = super(PreprocessLayer, self).get_config()                                                                                                                                                  
        config['mean'] = self.m                                                                                                                                                                             
        config['var'] = self.v                                                                                                                                                                              
        return config
```

And I call this layer with

```
L0 = PreprocessLayer(batch_size=20,mean=scaler.mean_,var=scaler.scale_)(IN)
```

The problem arises at

```
shape=(self.b,input_shape[1]),
```

Which give me the error (when batch_size is 20)

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,15] vs. [20,15]
     [[Node: preprocess_layer_1/sub = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_IN_0_0, preprocess_layer_1/mean/read)]]
```

From what I understand, since my weights (mean and var) need to have the same shape as the input x, the first axis poses problems when the batch_size is not a divisor of the training size because it will have different values during the training. That causes the crash because the shape has to be determined at compilation time and I cannot leave it blank.

Is there any way to have a dynamic value for the first value of shape ? If not, a work around for this problem ?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `BatchNormalization` layer after your input? Because you seem to be doing the exact same thing

Comment: Also I do not understand why the `batch_size` you pass is different than the `input_shape[0]` dimension?

Comment: Because I want to have a handle on what is going on in the preprocessing, also BatchNormalization works batch by batch and I would like to have the preprocessing on the whole dataset.
As for the second question it is because at compilation time input_shape = (None, 15)

Comment: If you have a `PreprocessLayer` after your `Input` layer, even that is going to work in batches, according to your `batch_size`. Can you tell me how many samples do you have in your each batch? Is it 32 or 20? Set `batch_size=batch_size_from_training` in your `PreprocessLayer` and let me know if you still get the error.

Comment: At first I used a batch_size of 20 (in ```PreprocessLayer``` and in ```model.fit```) and I get : 
```tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,15] vs. [20,15] ```

I then changed it to 32 and the error is ```Incompatible shapes: [28,15] vs. [32,15]```
In this case I guess it makes sense since my training size is 152540
 and 152540%32=28 (hence the first batch needs to be smaller so that the followings can be with a size of 32), but then I don't understand what happens in the first case since 152540%20 = 0

Comment: Why don't you use 20 for both? Wait: Did you say you use 20 for your `batch_size` and in the `Preprocess` layer and still get `Incompatible shapes: [32,15] vs. [20,15]` ?

Comment: BTW, I also don't think that you need to add `mean` and `var` as graph weights. you can calculate them from the batch in your `call` function. Is there a reason why you chose to do so?

Comment: Use a training size divisible by 32 and `shape=(input_shape[0], input_shape[1])` in place of `shape=(self.b,input_shape[1])`

Comment: I cannot use ```shape=(input_shape[0], input_shape[1])``` because ```input_shape = (None, 15)``` and this gives me error : ```TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'```

And yes, I do not understand why I get this ```[32,15]``` for any batch size but get ```[28,15]``` when I put a batch_size of 32.
I will try to play with the training and batch siz because this does not make sense

Comment: very strange!! Maybe use `output_shape` of the input layer to initialize it. It's really hard for me to say anything else without actually trying out the code now.

Comment: It gets weirder. When I use a batch size of 32 and a training set with a size equal to a multiple of 32 it works. But when I do that with another number, eg 24, and I make sure the training size is a multiple of 24 ... ```Incompatible shapes: [32,15] vs. [24,15]```.
What do you mean by using ```output_shape``` ? 
EDIT : the ```output_shape```  will always be ```(None,"something")``` at compilation for the input layer right ?

Comment: You can get the output shape of any intermediate layer in Keras. That's what i meant. Check if you have hard coded any size to 32 in your code which might be causing this problem.

Comment: Could you add more code? specifically your model

Comment: No hardcoded 32 anywhere. I will try to reproduce the problem on a dummy example, see if this happens again. If so I guess I should ask on the Keras Github ...

Comment: Okay. good luck. I feel there is a very simple thing we are missing somewhere but can't find it.

Comment: Found the reason (as you said, simple but I missed it) :
Before fitting the model I applied a check of the preprocessing for testing purposes:
```
preprocess = Model(inputs=[IN],outputs=[L0])
out_preprocess = preprocess.predict(x)
```
... but totally forgot about the batch_size in predict.
Now it works only if the batch_size is a multiple of the training size. Because if not, at the end of the epoch the remainder of the samples has a different length that the batch size. I guess I can just crop my training sample.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Remove it, and should work, right?

Comment: Yes it does. I will find a work around in order to make the training set a multiple of the batch size.
Thank you very much !

Comment: It should work now even if it's not a multiple I think. As long as you can pass the first dimension of your input to initialize the `batch_size` of your custom layer.

Comment: No, it works until the end of the epoch, then the remainder inputs in the last batch makes it fail.
EDIT : you mean pass the batch size as the first argument of shape ? 
Because the first dimension of input is None until the model is fitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue - which is a remainder different from the batch_size at the end of the epoch (due to the training and testing size not being a multiple of the batch size) that results in a `InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes` - here is my fix.

Since this remainder will always have a size smaller than the batch_size, what I did in the call function is to slice the weights like this :

```py
def call(self, x):                                                                                                                                            
        mean = self.mean[:K.shape(x)[0],:]                                                                                                                       
        std = self.std[:K.shape(x)[0],:]                                                                                                                        
        return (x-mean)/std
```

This works but it means that if a batch size larger than the one that initialized the layer is used to evaluate the model, the error will pop up again.

This is why I put at in the `__init__` :
`self.b = max(32,batch_size)`.

Because predict() uses by default batch_size = 32

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to add `mean` and `var` as weights. You can calculate them in your `call` function. I also do not exactly understand why you want to use this instead of `BatchNormalization` but anyway, maybe you can try this code

```
class PreprocessLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, eps=1e-6, **kwargs):
        self.eps = eps
        super(PreprocessLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(PreprocessLayer, self).build(input_shape)
    def call(self, x):
        mean = K.mean(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        std = K.std(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        return (x - mean) / (std + self.eps)
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

`eps` is to avoid division by 0.

I do not guarantee this will work, but maybe give it a try.

Comment: This will probably work, I did something similar before but instead I had used K.variables for ```mean``` and ```std``` (initialized with the mean and std from training set) because these were computed on the whole sample (while here you only do it for a batch that can be small).

Comment: My only issue was that when the model is loaded, I have to provide the mean and std parameters and I don't want to because when applied on another sample they can be different. This is the reason why I want to define ```mean``` and ```std``` as weights, this way they will be saved in the ```weights.h5 ``` file that is loaded with the model.


The entire point is to have a portable model, that can be used directly on unknow data without the need to preprocess them.

Comment: Ya, I do not understand why you want them as weights. is there a specific reason to normalize your test data by the `mean` and `var` of your training data? Otherwise, the `BatchNormalization` or a simple custom layer like this takes care of the process, per batch.

Comment: You don't need to provide mean and std for a `BatchNormalization`, neither for a custom layer. They will calculate the mean and std for each batch and normalize your data based on that. You can also normalize your data easily in the preprocessing steps before you feed in into your network. So, I don't actually see the problem that you mention.

Comment: I can normalize the data before the neural network, which is in fact what I have been doing before. I just want to have that step included in the network now, it is easier to use it later and avoid this external preprocessing.

I am not fond of ```BatchNormalization``` because there is no handle to check what it is doing. Also I don't how how it behaves when I load the model and apply it on unknown data.